# BeautifulSoup adds content when I run find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape listings from yp.com, and in building the code, I am able to isolate the section with the names `(div class="search-results organic")`, but then when I run `find_all()` on that content, it returns listings outside that section.

The URL is http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=septic&geo_location_terms=80521

Here is what I am running:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
import xml
import requests
from urlparse import urlparse

filename = "webspyorganictag.html"
term = "septic"
zipcode = "80521"
url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms="+ term +"&geo_location_terms="+ zipcode

with open(filename, "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write("Information from the organic<br>")

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
organic = soup.find("div", {"class": "search-results organic"})

with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str(organic))
```

And this returns just the content in the organic listings section. There are 30 listings.

Then, I add:

```
listings = organic.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})
i = 1
with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
    for listing in listings:
        myfile.write("This is listing " + str(i) + "<br>")
        myfile.write(str(listing) + "<br>")
        i += 1
```

And this returns the original 30 listings plus 10 more listings from (aside id="main-aside") which is not included in the variable 'organic'.

Shouldn't calling `organic.find_all()` limit the scope to the data that was in the variable 'organic'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `"xml"` you are finding 41 `class="info">` with `soup.find("div", {"class": "search-results organic"})` so it is not surprising that you get 41 returned with find_all. You are getting the other elements returned which can easily be seen by looking at what organic returns i.e `href="/wray-co/mip/ritcheys-redi-mix-precast-inc-10367117?lid=1000575822573"`, `href="/longmont-co/mip/rays-backhoe-service-6327932?lid=216924340"` and every other listing from the ten featured.

If you look at line 41 of the html you write it also contains:

`href="/wray-co/mip/ritcheys-redi-mix-precast-inc-10367117?lid=1000575822573"` which is the last of the featured listings.

The problem is the parser, if you change your parser to `"lxml"`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

organic = soup.find("div", {"class": "search-results organic"})

print(len(organic.find_all("h3",{"class":"info"})))
30
```

Or use `html.parser`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser") 

organic = soup.find("div", {"class": "search-results organic"})

print(len(organic.find_all("div",{"class":"info"})))
30
```

You get the correct result.

Comment: Until reading carefully the last paragraphs of the OP - I thought you'd finally lost it :) (didn't dv though)

Comment: OP knows where these 10 additional entries came from. He mentions `<aside id="main-aside">` in the post.

Comment: There are 10, but they aren't included in organic's content. They show up when i run find_all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it is obvious, that `organic` includes items from the sidebar. I do not understand _why_ it includes them.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I use Chrome Developer Tools and when I search for `div.organic`'s content I get [following results](http://pastebin.com/ncApL3kB) This confuses me a lot

Comment: @Alik,  the parser is actually the problem.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I figured it out a few minutes ago. BeatufulSoup supresses all exceptions from parsers and does nothing to handle them

Comment: @Alik, different parsers parse the html in different ways, I have never used xml.

Comment: Awesome work, @PadraicCunningham! I just switched to lxml and it returns the 30 organic listings. I still can't figure out why it only prints the 30 listings when I run find, but then when I run find_all on the results, there are 10 more listings. At any rate, this solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaMeyer, no worries,  for me I get 41 listings using xml so not sure exactly what is happening but sometimes different parsers give very different output, if you `from bs4 import diagnose` and run `diagnose.diagnose(r.content)` on the source you will see how each parser handles the source